# Finding standard deviations of columns of a matrix

Tags: matrix, stata

Suppose I have a matrix generated by the following code:

```
matrix A = (1,2\2,5\.,7\.,10\.,2\.,13)
```

I want to find the standard deviation of each column of the matrix (there are two in this example, so I want to compute two standard deviations). As per advice from statalist [post](https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-01/msg00905.html), I attempted Mata code as follows:

```
mata: st_matrix("testing", diagonal(sqrt(variance(st_matrix("A")))))
matrix list testing
```

However, the standard deviation I get from this code is different from the standard deviation I compute using MS Excel. I suspect that this is because of the missing numbers.

How can I compute correct standard deviations of the columns of the matrix?

Comment: What is "the column"? That matrix has two columns. But you are computing one variance. I've interpreted your question in terms of a matrix collapsed to a vector.

Comment: @Emperor Sai jumped the other way in their answer.

Comment: @NickCox I believe Sai's answer is what I wanted to describe, but I have yet to test it yet. I'm not completely sure what that variance function does, because when I do matrix list, it does show two variances. I have edited the question to make it more clear. Also that svmat A and su A? seems to be working out too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're working in Stata any way, an alternative starts from pushing the matrix into two or more variables.

```
matrix A = (1, 2 \ 2, 5 \ ., 7 \ ., 10 \ ., 2 \ ., 13)
svmat A 
su A?
```

The wildcard would need modification for 10 or more columns.

For reference, a calculation of the standard deviation of the entire matrix first pushes the matrix into a vector:

```
mat Avec = vec(A)
svmat Avec
su Avec1
```

Comment: The last two codes seems to be working as intended! Would you mind describing what that question mark is doing after summarize? Looks like its function is very similar to *

Comment: Standard syntax for a wildcard as documented at `help varlist`. In your example `svmat A` yields new variables `A1 A2` and `A?` catches both.